# Copy constructors in the core domain

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have domain entities that are extended with classes in the infrastructure layer to encapsulate implementation details:

```
MyDomainEntity {
    List<SupportingDomain> children
}

SupportingDomain { ... }

SqlSupportingDomain extends SupportingDomain {
    Long version
}
```

I have a need to deep copy MyDomainEntity, something like this:

```
public MyDomainEntity(MyDomainEntity other) {
    this.children = other.children.stream()
        .map(d -> (d instanceof SqlSupportingDomain) ? new SqlSupportingDomain((SqlSupportingDomain) d) : new SupportingDomain(d))
}
```

Of course, this approach leaks infrastructure details into the core domain (the SqlSupportingDomain check), which is undesirable.

How might someone handle such a situation? Is there perhaps a better approach for keeping infrastructure and domain concerns apart?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a virtual method copy() in SupportingDomain class that returns a copy of the instance, then override it in the SqlSupportingDomain class and call this method in the map function. 
With that you would encapsulate the copy logic in the corresponding class and avoid casting.